Efficiently sampling $k$ elements from the powerset while avoiding space blow up
Is there a way that I can space efficiently sample $k$ elements from $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,\ldots, n\})$ without replacement?
For instance, the naive approach would be as follows in Python:
from random import sample

# From https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) → () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def power_sample(n, k):
    pow_set = list(powerset(range(1,n+1)))
    return sample(pow_set, k)

But this requires generating the powerset and placing it in memory with pow_set. This blows up quite a bit in terms of memory very quickly. This question provides a solution to generating a single random element, but I do not see a way to easily generalize to select $k$ elements without replacement. Is there a way to avoid this memory blow up?

If a set S has n elements, then its power set has 2^n elements and there is a one-to-one mapping between the n bit integers and there elements of the power set.
To find random elements of the power set, generate random n bit numbers using the same rules, then map each of the numbers to an element of the power set.
It would never occur to you to store all possible n bit numbers to pick some random n-bit numbers; and likewise there is no need to build and store the power set.
If n is close to 64 then you need to make sure that your random number generator can actually produce 64 bit numbers where every bit is random, in order to get random power set elements. And if n is greater than 64 then you need to generate and store more than one 64 bit word with a random 64 bit number.

Does this sample without replacement though? I would think it is possible to get a copy of the same set this way which is something I am trying to avoid.

@Dair If you hit a copy at any time, run it again. The probability of hitting a copy is low $\frac{k}{2^n}$ which means the expected number of one element samples you would have to do $\approx k$

Even if $k$ is large or comparable to $2^n$, the total number of expected samples $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{2^n}{2^n-i} \in \mathcal{O}(n k)$

@EnEm I feel dumb now. For some reason I was thinking running again would mess up the distribution. Thanks.

Also note that if your $k$ is fairly large then you can't really avoid the $\Theta(k)$ storage requirement, but you can generally make the check for whether you've pulled a duplicate sample run quickly (e.g., $O(\log k)$ ) by maintaining a sorted list of pulled samples, using a hash table, etc.
